# Adding @import statement in a dynamic stylesheet for IE7+

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, dynamic-css

I have a problem with adding a dynamic style element with @import statements for IE. Try this:

```
var string = '@import url(test.css)';
var style = document.createElement('style');

if (style.styleSheet) { // IE
    style.styleSheet.cssText = string;
} else {
    var cssText = document.createTextNode(string);
    style.appendChild(cssText);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

This works for FF/Chrome but not IE. It seems to recognize `style.styleSheets.imports`, but it will not apply the imported stylesheet. Is this a bug or limitation?

Comment: Why not use a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css" ...` tag?

Comment: @digitalFresh: because I have no control over the inserted CSS string in this case.

Comment: When are you performing the javascript? As it may be a case of the DOM not fully loading before you try the javascript. Best bet would be to try it as the very last thing on the page inside the body (if it's not already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many older browsers can't process varying forms of the @import directive, this can be used to hide css from them. Check http://www.w3development.de/css/hide_css_from_browsers/import/ for details.

The `@import` directives must come first in a style sheet, or else they'll be ignored. however IE doesn't ignore misplaced `@import` directives.

**Edit**: See the [addImport method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531193%28VS.85%29.aspx) for injecting style sheets in IE.

Comment: This is not the issue here, it works fine when adding a style tag in the HTML, the problem arises when injecting via DOM.